# SharePoint 2016 search result returning error message - searchservice.svc is unavailable

Tags: search

I have created a new SSA on SharePoint 2016, all the search components looks fine. However when I try to search for something I get the below error message.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please verify whether the below TCP port is opened in the firewall between the application and web front end server:

TCP 808   Search – Query processing component
          Windows Communication Foundation communication

TCP 32843 Communication between Web servers and service applications

TCP 32844   Communication between Web servers and service applications

And also **restart the search service** from windows service followed by **IIS/RESET** and try again.

For details port details for SharePoint 2016, refer to the below article:

[SharePoint 2016 – TCP/IP Ports](https://blogit.create.pt/fabiocarvalho/2017/02/14/sharepoint-2016-tcpip-ports/)

Comment: Thanks for your message, our SharePoint UAT environment are not behind the firewall